# Style Android Time Picker

Tags: android, dialog, datetimepicker

I have used the time picker supplied by android I am trying to find a way to style the buttons. I have managed to do this for other dialog but as this is supplied by android I do not have the xml file.

Is there anyway to get hold of the xml file and store in my app rather than it referring to the default layout?

Or is this not possible and does it have to be styled in code?

Thank you for your help